# Zstack alignment issue on NavigationView

Tags: swiftui, zstack

Two circles on Zstack is not align if view is render on NavigationView.

```
struct SpinnerView: View {
 
    @State private var isLoading = false
 
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color(.systemGray5), lineWidth: 7)
                    .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: 0.2)
                    .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 7)
                    .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isLoading ? 360 : 0))
                    .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
                    .onAppear() {
                        self.isLoading = true
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reproduce your problem, I moved `NavigationView` to a start screen `ContentView` and launch `SpinnerView` with a `NavigationLink`.  Once I do that, I can see the *falling animation*.

If you turn the animation into an explicit animation triggered by `withAnimation()`, and delay it until the view loads, you can avoid the extra movement introduced by the `NavigationView`.  By changing `isLoading` to `true` initially, and then setting it to `false` in `onAppear` before calling `withAnimation`, the `false` state which occurs after the view is loaded will be established (for the purposes of the animation) as the *before* state.  Then, when `isLoading` is set to `true` in the `withAnimation` block, the animation will proceed.  This avoids including the movement caused by imbedding the screen in a navigation screen because this all happens before `isLoading` is set to `false`.

```
struct SpinnerView: View {
    
    @State private var isLoading = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(Color(.systemGray5), lineWidth: 7)
                .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: 0.2)
                .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 7)
                .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isLoading ? 360 : 0))
                .onAppear() {
                    self.isLoading = false
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                        self.isLoading = true
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Go to spinner view", destination: SpinnerView())
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is it running in the simulator:

[image: Demo running in simulator]

Comment: Now on actual screen, SpinnerView is falling from and again going back to top

Comment: I updated the answer to fix the subsequent issue that you were seeing.

Comment: How did that work for you?

Comment: it worked thnx :)